# Morphisms with connected fibres and rational functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex projective varieties and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism with connected fibres. Is it true that any element of $\mathbb C(X)\setminus f^*\mathbb C(Y)$ is transcendental over $f^*\mathbb C(Y)$?

Comment: Think of the case where $Y$ is a point.

Comment: Sorry, the question was badly formulated, I have rewritten it.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to asking whether $\mathbb{C}(X)$ has a subfield which is a nontrivial algebraic extension of $f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y)$.  I think the answer is yes.  Suppose that there is an intermediate field $L \subset \mathbb{C}(X)$ where $L$ is a nontrivial algebraic extension of $f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y)$.  We know that the extension $L / f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y)$ is also finite, because $X \to Y$ is a morphism of varieties and therefore of finite type; let $d \geq 2$ be its degree.  The field inclusions $f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y) \subset L \subset \mathbb{C}(X)$ correspond to a composition of surjective morphisms $X \to Y' \to Y$, where $Y'$ is a variety whose function field is $L$.  Over a $\mathbb{C}$-point of $Y$, the fiber in $Y'$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec} (\mathbb{C}^{\oplus d})$ and is therefore not connected.  The fact that the fiber in $X$ is also not connected then follows from continuity of the morphisms.  Since that violates your hypothesis, $\mathbb{C}(X) \setminus f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y)$ has no elements which are algebraic over $f^{*}\mathbb{C}(Y)$.

Comment: How are you getting the morphism $Y' \to Y$?  A map between the function fields gives a dominant rational map, not a morphism.  And then some care is needed when talking about the fibers.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I suppose the main thing would be to argue that the rational map $Y' \to Y$ is defined on an entire fiber over some closed point of $Y$.

Comment: See Example 2.1.12 of Lazarsfeld's "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: @Mark: you can take $Y'$ to be the integral closure of $Y$ in $L$. If $X$ is normal, then $X \to Y$ has to factor through $Y'$. In this case, a *general* fibre will be $\mathbb C^d$ (since $Y' \to Y$ is generically finite étale, hence finite étale on some open). Note however that $Y' \to Y$ need not even be flat, so there could be fibres of different length.